# How to enable edge-to-edge display for any app in Android Pie?

Tags: 9.0-pie, oxygenos, oneplus-6, immersive-mode

I recently upgraded my OnePlus 6 from Android Oreo to Pie (OxygenOS 9.0.8; **rooted**).  This release came up with a restriction that only the apps listed under *Settings → Display → Apps to display in fullscreen* can use edge-to-edge display (full immersive mode including notch area). As of now, YouTube app (using YouTube Vanced v14.21.54) is not shown in that list, and when I enable immersive mode that app doesn't make use of the notch area at all.

Here's how immersive mode looks like with and without notch area:

<sub>(Images edited. Courtesy of OnePlus)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

One thing I noticed is that, for the apps in the list if they are set to be launched in fullscreen (including notch area) the appops operation APP_SCREEN_COMPAT is set to *deny*, while in default state, it is set to *ignore*. Manually changing it via adb to *allow* further reduces the immersive mode screen estate.

I tried adding that operation (op) manually for YouTube app but it didn't make any change, including when I force-stopped the app and even restarted the device. The op is reflected in appops query though.

I used this command:

```
adb shell appops set com.google.android.youtube APP_SCREEN_COMPAT deny
```

I also tried changing *policy_control* global settings property to `immersive.full=com.google.android.youtube` but it didn't make any difference either.

I came across some forums where users shared similar problem with their choice of apps with no solution in sight. I also looked for some related Magisk and EdXposed solution but found none. GravityBox [P] doesn't have any feature either.

So, how do I make sure any of my app can use edge-to-edge display in immersive mode?